# Angularjs ng-repeat rendering more items than are in the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have the following code:

```
    <div class="carousel" ng-if="novedadesEmpleados.cumpleanosDeHoy.length">
            <div ng-repeat="empleado in novedadesEmpleados.todaysBirthdays" carousel-renderer class="event-card">

                <birthday-card empleado="empleado" card-notifier></birthday-card>

            </div>
    </div>
```

Which used to work fine until I changed from using Bootstrap Carousel to [Tiny Slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider).

The array currently has 2 elements in it, however the HTML is rendering 6, 4 oh which are just showing the default angularjs text (name of properties in curly brackets) and the other 2 are displaying the correct information.

What could be causing this? The two directives are used to call the Tiny Slider initializer after they're done rendering:

```
angular.module('PortalIntranet').directive('cardNotifier', function ($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        if(scope.$last)
            scope.$emit('FinishedRendering'); 
    }
});

angular.module('PortalIntranet').directive('carouselRenderer', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on('FinishedRendering', function (event) {
            var slider = tns({
                container: '.card-slider',
                autoplay: true,
                slideBy: 'page',
                autoplayTimeout: 3500,
                speed: 750,
                autoplayButton: false,
                nav: false,
                autoplayButtonOutput: false,
                controls: false
            });
            console.log(slider);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not likely displaying more items then are in the array.  First, make sure your data is clean.

I believe the root ;) of your problem is in the directives and the rootScope.  Most likely you need have the check when the condition is met on the rootScope or scope of the "carouselRenderer" not on the scope of the "cardNotifier".  i.e.

```
if (scope.$parent.$last)
```

You want the last of the repeated items in the parent scope.

Also, as a side note, make sure your css classes are in the right place.  Why is the "event-card" on the carousel-renderer and not on the birthday-card?

Comment: Is any other change required for your code to be implemented? Simply changing scope.$last to scope.$parent.$last makes it to that the event is never fired.